# Where do I save an Image for calling it with cv::imread

Tags: ros, opencv, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!
I'm using opencv for reading an image that later I'm going to use as a reference in my ROS node, the problem is that my code isn't reading it.
I saved it in the src folder inside the package folder, that is, in the same folder as the .cpp
Here is the code that does it:

```
    cv_ptr=cv_bridge::toCvCopy(msg, sensor_msgs::image_encodings::BGR8);
    cv::Mat img2;
    //Thresholding
    cv::cvtColor(cv_ptr->image,img2,CV_BGR2GRAY);
    Mat img1 = imread("bucher.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE );
    if( img1.empty() ) {
      printf("Error occured, image not read correctly");
            }
```

The terminal is always showing me that error, then it isnt reading correctly the image.
I don't know if maybe I have to modify something in the CMakeLists.txt to be able to use the image.

I apreciate your help, thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/212287/where-do-i-save-an-image-for-calling-it-with-cv::imread/) by [erivera1802](https://answers.ros.org/users/22029/erivera1802/) on ROS Answers with karma: 59 on 2015-06-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Pass the location of the image as a param in a launch file like:

```
<param name="image" value="$(find your_pkg)/src/bucher.jpg">
```

Or use find package in the source as in http://wiki.ros.org/Packages#C.2B-.2B-

```
std::string image = ros::package::getPath("your_pkg") + "/src/bucher.jpg";
```

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2015-06-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [erivera1802](https://answers.ros.org/users/22029/erivera1802/) on 2015-06-26**:
for the second solution, where goes that line?.
And where you write "your_pkg" i write the name of the package or the entire path?
Then image would be a ROS type image, so i would need to convert it with cv-bridge?
Thanks a lot!·

**Comment by [cyborg-x1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1900/cyborg-x1/) on 2015-06-26**:
I would prefer the first one ... hard coded paths ... well ... are just ugly for reusing your node, well except you know that nobody ever will change it for any reason, like an icon for an application for example ...

**Comment by [erivera1802](https://answers.ros.org/users/22029/erivera1802/) on 2015-06-26**:
The problem is that i havent used any launch file yet. But if I do so, in my code i just call image und is an image type message?
Thanks

**Comment by [erivera1802](https://answers.ros.org/users/22029/erivera1802/) on 2015-06-26**:
Oooook I wasnt understanding at all. Yep, lucasw solution worked perfectly!

Thanks